# How to open URL in same window and in same tab

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, popup

I have this LinkButton:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbiOpen" runat="server" />
```

and my Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbiOpen.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:window.location.href('New.aspx');"); 
}
```

If a user clicks on the LinkButton a popup should open. But it doesn't work. When I click on nothing happens.

When I Change `window.location.href = window.open` it works, but it opens in another tab.

Comment: Did you try "javascript:window.location.href='New.aspx';"

Comment: Why do you need it to be `asp:LinkButton` and not simple `a href`?

Comment: window.location.assign("New.aspx");

Comment: Posted how to open on a new window ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbiOpen" runat="server">Example</asp:LinkButton>


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbiOpen.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('New.aspx', 'New Window', 'width=200,height=100')");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
window.open("New.aspx", "_self"); // will open in the same windows

window.location.href = "New.aspx"; // will open in a new window
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbiOpen" OnClientClick="window.open('New.aspx', '_self');return false;" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
```